# How to create a Postgres Identity database for use with ASP.NET Core with dotnet-ef?

Tags: asp.net-identity, postgresql-13

After much research and trial and error here are the steps that I have found that works:

**Environment**:

- Windows 10
- Postgres 13
- ASP.NET Core 5

Steps to create:

1. Create the Identity database on Postgress 13.
2. `GRANT ALL ON DATABASE dbname TO user;`
3. Create an ASP.NET Core project targeting .NET 5 (net5.0) with Individual Authorization.
4. Add the connection string to the `appsetting.json` file.
5. Add the `<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="5.0.2" />` to the .csproj file.
6. If the package exits for using SqLite -- remove it.
7. Rebuild Solution.
8. In the Startup.cs, change `.UsingSqlServer`  to `,Npgsql`.
9. Save and rebuild.
10. In the Developer PowerShell run:
11. `dotnet-ef migrations remove` If there are no errors then run:
12. `dotnet-ef migrations add InitialIdent` If there are no errors run:
13. 'dotnet-ef' database update`

Now there should be the identity tables in your Postgres database.

Comment: marc-s -- Thanks for the edits! Much appreciated.

Comment: With .NET Core 7+ there are a couple changes:

Step 5, make sure you have the proper version of both the Npgsql and Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.  Better to use the Nuget utility in your IDE or the CLI instead of editing the .csproj file.

Step 8, this is in Program.cs, change options.UseSqlServer to .UseNpgsql

Also, "dotnet-ef" can be "dotnet ef" (without the dash)

Answer (score 0):

These steps work for core 5 but not core 3.